# in progress vs on progress

Tags: prepositions

> The expansion and definition of a brand is always, to a certain
>   extent, work in progress. [this example from Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ko/%EC%82%AC%EC%A0%84/%EC%98%81%EC%96%B4/work-in-progress)

I want to know why 'on' cannot be used in the sentence.

In my opinion, 'Progress' means that 'Going to the aim', so that 'in' is more correct than 'on' because we cannot see obviously how the progress is going on at least in the sentence.
To sum up, I think if we ***can*** see obviously how a work is going on, 'on progress' is more appropriate, but if we ***can't*** see obviously how a work is going on, 'in progress' is better.

Is my thinking correct?

Comment: How can you judge what is appropriate? According to your mother tongue? You can't change the language. You can only study how to use it naturally.

Comment: @V.V. I do not judge what is fine according to my native language. I judge it based on the meaning of English preposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Posting as an answer because I don't have enough reputation for a comment).

@SIS, as a non native English speaker I totally understand that might not make sense. However, as in every language, you have your own way of writing and structuring things. Sometimes, if you analyse it, you think it doesn't make sense, but that's how language work, and at a certain point in my life I just had to start accepting that some things are written in that way. Period.

Remember also that in most languages, including of course English, you have "the rules", and but you also have "the exceptions".

I think the case of "in progress" is a mixture of all these issues.

You might want to have a look at [this link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/work-in-progress).

Comment: I agree to your opinion, and I know that there are many exceptions in languages, but I just only wanted to know if there is an acceptable reason why it is only correct.